# Problem with laravel/ui while installing laravel-dompdf laravel8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, dompdf, laravel-dompdf, laravel-ui

Can someone help  me to fix it?

- while installing

> composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

- Errors

```
Problem 1
    - laravel/ui is locked to version v2.3.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
  Problem 2
    - nette/schema v1.2.1 requires php >=7.1 <8.1 -> your php version (8.1.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - league/commonmark 2.0.2 requires league/config ^1.1.1 -> satisfiable by league/config[v1.1.1].
    - laravel/framework v8.61.0 requires league/commonmark ^1.3|^2.0 -> satisfiable by league/commonmark[2.0.2].
    - league/config v1.1.1 requires nette/schema ^1.2 -> satisfiable by nette/schema[v1.2.1].
    - laravel/framework is locked to version v8.61.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

- composer.json

```
"require": {
....
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.54",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^6.1",
        "livewire/livewire": "^2.5",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
....
    },
```

composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Comment: what's your composer version?

Comment: Composer version 2.3.7 2022-06-06